# change the color of titlebar of window app

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I want to change the color of the title bar of a dialog box. I know there is WM_NCPAINT which is used to paint the non client area. But I don't find a good example of WM_PAINT where the color is changed to a specific color.

Comment: Before saying "don't do that", I feel obligated to ask: why?

Comment: client want it black.

Comment: I feel your pain. Does he want all Dalog title bar black, or just this one? How about the actice/inactive difference?

Comment: all Dialog Box.and no active/inactive difference.

Comment: You mean: all Dialog Box displayed by your program, but not the Dialog Box displayed by other programs?

Comment: yes only dialog box from my program

Comment: Don't try to change standard window. In Windows 7 title bar can be transparent, and there such hacks make no sense. Draw your own box.

Comment: Are you an experimented Win32 programmer, willing to implement your own Window Class, derived from "#32770"?

Comment: even i draw the dialog box using resource editor still need to use wm_ncpaint to change the color

Comment: Non-client frame painting with WM_NCPAINT was feasible in the olden days.  But Microsoft's focus on giving every Windows version its own look-and-feel made it drastically impractical.  If the client wants his window frame black then he can easily do so by changing his theme settings, no reason for you to commit to code that you really don't want to have to maintain.